# Android-12 - BLE only returns status 0 in onConnectionStateChange Callback

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-12

I am facing one issue related to BLE’s behavior in our application. In Android 11 and below, On Ble disconnection, we used to get different status codes in onConnectionStateChange callback like status 8 is for out range, 19 is peripheral disconnection etc and For programmatic disconnection, it was returning 0.  
However starting from Android 12 the BLE API is always returning 0 regardless of it is programmatic disconnection or due to any other reason.

In our application, we are performing some operations based on if the disconnection was unexpected(Out of range, peripheral initiated, etc) or it was programmatic. Now there is no way to distinguish the difference for BLE disconnection reason on Android 12 devices. And this creates issues in our application.

Has anyone faced this issue with BLE’s behavior in your application running on an android 12 devices and found any solution for it?

Also, This change in android 12 is not mentioned anywhere in the android developer’s documentation.

Here is the callback which i am using to get connection status change : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)

Comment: yes, I also noticed that it reports a connection timeout as 0. Not sure if Google did this intentionally or not.

Answer (score 0):

I also find it very annoying.
The question is also asked here ([Android 12 BLE always returning status 0 on disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387604/)) and gives a little more context.